# How does iptables determine which packets are multicast?

Tags: linux, security, iptables, firewall, multicast

Are packets assumed to be multicast solely based on their ip address?  I've been looking at the [RFC 1112](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1112.txt) and a quick scan doesn't appear to indicate any other flags on the ip packet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IP multicast address ranges are defined in the standard. You have a look at them [here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/multicast-addresses/multicast-addresses.xml) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address).